# Variable not changing inside function once changed for next use

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove columns from a table on the click of a button, however; when I use the button and it removes the last column, if I then want to remove another column I run into an issue where a critical variable isn't updated.

JS:

```
function deleteCol(){   
debugger;

var tds = document.getElementById("icol").value;

var cold = document.getElementsByClassName(tds-1);

for (var i = 0; i < tds; i++) {
    var inc = 0;
    var lastCol = cold[inc];
    lastCol.remove();

}
    tds--;

}
```

Here I am trying to alter the value of tds after the loop has taken place, but when I next use the button it uses the initial tds value over again and not the updated version, can someone explain to me why it doesn't re assign the tds variable for when I use it next time? *edit* the function I have here is basically removing the last cell on each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only updating a variable rather than the live attribute `value`, instead do this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("icol");
var tds = input.value;
.
.
.
input.value = --tds
```

Comment: I see, thank you for telling me this, I am quite new to JS and haven't seen this surprisingly.